# How to retrieve path and filename of a spreadsheet being imported in SQL developer?

Tags: sql, import, filenames, spreadsheet, oracle-sqldeveloper

I imported an excel spreadsheet into Oracle SQL Developer and I want to know how to retrieve the path of the file?

The original spreadsheets on my computer are not all located in the same folders as they are categorized into many subfolders, but are all within one directory. Importing the spreadsheets into sql developer is not a problem (I am currently just making a new external table for each spreadsheet) but I want to obtain the path and filename of each of the spreadsheets imported (so I would know where that source file came from on my computer) and have it within a new column in the tables or making a new table for just the paths and reference the data to it or something).

Is there a way to do it in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation for SQL Developer there doesn't appear to be a field you can reference to obtain the filename during import.

[SQL Developer User's Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18464_01/doc.30/e17472/dialogs.htm) - Section 5.32

Your best bet may be to do the import with an external script (shell script, powershell, etc) which could reference the filename and insert that into a table of your choosing once the import had succeeded.